# Cynetworkx library doesn't recognize Cython upon import: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cython'

Tags: python, installation, networkx, cython

I am trying to use the [Cython](https://github.com/cython) and [cynetworkx](https://github.com/pattern-inc/cynetworkx) library in a pycharm environment (Python version 3.10).

I already installed Cython without problems via Settings->Python Interpreter.
Afterwards when I try to install cynetworkx in the same way I get the following error message:

> Collecting cynetworkx   Using cached
> cynetworkx-2.2rc1.dev20180527181709.tar.gz (14.8 MB)   Installing
> build dependencies: started   Installing build dependencies: finished
> with status 'done'   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
> Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
>
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.   exit code: 1
>
> (...)
>
> "C:\Users\replacedusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py",
> line 3, in 
> import cython   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cython'   [end of output]
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. exit
> code: 1
>
> See above for output.
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.

How can I fix this issue?